# How to stop randome mac address when using usb tethering of android in windows

Tags: android

I noticed that the mac address always change when enable usb tethering in andoird, I want to know how to use a static mac address for it?

I have alredy tested "change registry", but it not works.

Comment: Please use https://stackexchange.com/ for this type of Questions.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, it seems impossible. I tried everything even "ip link set rndis0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" in an Android terminal and the MAC address won't change in Windows. Even if you force a static IP in control panel it will automatically change if you disconnect/reconnect. 
The issue for me is that it creates automatically a new profile in Windows, and it's boring to always set the new network number 183 as private. Even with a static IPv4 address, the network number 184 will be created because of the another different mac address and nothing is possible. A network bridge won't fix it.

I also tried some softwares like Technitium MAC Address Changer v6 but the MAC address isn't permanent as it is set, it doesn't work.